# Cannot install pandas package on pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have trouble installing pandas package on Pycharm

I get the following error

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\merta\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2> pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.1.1.tar.gz (4.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\merta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d6d90p2m\pandas_68ffe712dae546f491bf76344985b59e C:\Users\merta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d6d90p2m\pandas_68ffe712dae546f491bf76344985b59e\.mesonpy-wxwl0ax
i\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\merta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d6d90p2m\pandas_68ffe712dae546f491bf76344985b59e\.mesonpy-wxwl0axi\build\meson-python-native-fil
e.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\merta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d6d90p2m\pandas_68ffe712dae546f491bf76344985b59e
      Build dir: C:\Users\merta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d6d90p2m\pandas_68ffe712dae546f491bf76344985b59e\.mesonpy-wxwl0axi\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.1.1
     
      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe
     
      A full log can be found at C:\Users\merta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d6d90p2m\pandas_68ffe712dae546f491bf76344985b59e\.mesonpy-wxwl0axi\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`
```

I tried changing the interpreter, installing pandas through the terminal and the pycharm option but it won't work

I don't understand the link with vswhere

Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049036/installation-of-sklearn-scipy-fails-in-pycharm-ide-with-could-not-find-vswhere

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to issues with building the Pandas package using Meson, which is a build system. It appears to be trying to locate a tool called vswhere.exe from Microsoft Visual Studio, and it's failing to find it. This could be due to an incomplete or incorrect installation of Visual Studio or a misconfiguration.

To resolve this issue:

1. Install Visual Studio
2. Upgrade Pip and Setuptools

```
python -m pip install --upgrade 
pip python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

3. Use a Virtual Environment

```
python -m venv myenv

.\myenv\Scripts\Activate
```

4. Use Pre-built

```
pip install pandas==2.1.1
```

if pandas installation does not work use

```
conda install pandas
```