# Installing pandas in the pycharm and show error: could not find Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pycharm, ide

As shown in the pic, I'd like to install pandas, however, it shows cannot find the vswhere.exe.
Here is the thing, at first I download Microsoft as my IDE but later I uninstall it for some reason and then I download pycharm. Not sure if the reason is related to what I have done, and if yes, how can I change the route of this vswhere.exe things. Great thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KkFg.png)

I have already updated my pip tool to the latest version, and the message show the error is not a problem from pip. So far I am so confused. Many thanks for answering.

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: try this: `pip install vswhere`. This was answered in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049036/installation-of-sklearn-scipy-fails-in-pycharm-ide-with-could-not-find-vswhere)